# In Flutter how to send updates for android app and force users to update?

Tags: android, flutter

In Flutter how can I manage versions and send updates or patches for android application and force users to update. I also want to stop users how haven't updated. My approach would be checking the version at very first page of the application and display an alert? Is that the way?

Comment: Sounds pretty ugly. It might take a few days for updates to file down.
you can check the current installed version here
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_info

Comment: try package- https://pub.dev/packages/native_updater

Answer (score 3):

Flutter (more precisely Dart) is not different from a java application on that point, and there are multiple solutions we can imagine. Here are a few of them :

- You can call the play store and parse the result to get the current
  version of you application and display a message to the user
  preventing him to use his version of the app (subject to changes and not easy to follow)
- You can also use your own server and enable your app to read the
  current version from there.
- If your application does some calls to an API that you manage, you can include the app 
  version in each call and return a special error code to the application if the version 
  is outdated

Answer (score 1):

If your application does some calls to an API that you manage, you can include the app version in each call and return a special error code to the application if the version is outdated.

Comment: You should not steal others answers to make it yours.